# Pass value from an application event to a form (this form launch events for that appication) VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, winforms, class

I am using a form to active an event for an application and I would like to pass a value from this event to a textbox on that form. But It does not add that value to its textbox. Please guide me in this case.

'Code in Module

```
Public Module InventorEvents

Private WithEvents m_onDocumentChangeEvent As Inventor.ApplicationEvents
Private WithEvents m_appEvents As Inventor.ApplicationEvents

Private g_inventorApplication As Inventor.Application
Private DocumentObject As Inventor.Document

Public Sub ActiveEvents()

    g_inventorApplication = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Inventor.Application")

    DocumentObject = g_inventorApplication.ActiveDocument

    m_onDocumentChangeEvent = g_inventorApplication.ApplicationEvents

    m_appEvents = g_inventorApplication.ApplicationEvents

End Sub

Private Sub m_onDocumentChangeEvent_OnDocumentChange(ByVal DocumentObject As Inventor.Document,
                                                     ByVal BeforeOrAfter As EventTimingEnum,
                                                     ByVal ReasonsForChange As CommandTypesEnum,
                                                     ByVal Context As NameValueMap,
                                                     ByRef HandlingCode As HandlingCodeEnum) Handles m_onDocumentChangeEvent.OnDocumentChange


    If BeforeOrAfter = EventTimingEnum.kAfter Then

        Call _formCommands.AddText($"OnActivateDocument : {DocumentObject.DisplayName}")

    End If

End Sub

End Module
```

'Code in Form

```
Public Class _formCommands

Private Sub _formCommands_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call InventorEvents.ActiveEvents()
End Sub

Public Sub AddText(str As String)
    _tboxStatus.AppendText(str + System.Environment.NewLine)
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Whether or not the text ends up in the `TextBox` should not be how you determine what's happening here. You're a developer, not a user. Act like one. Use the debugger to watch your code in action. Is the event handler in your module executed or not?

Comment: If the event is raised and that AddText call executed then I'd guess that the issue is the fact that you're referring to the default instance of that form type in your module and the instance you're actually looking at is not the default instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Class Form1
Dim txtbox0 As TextBox = Nothing
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    txtbox0 = TextBox1
    With txtbox0
        .Text = "Hello"
    End With

    'When you need a handler you can write this or similar:
    AddHandler txtbox0.Click, AddressOf mytxtbox0_event_click
    'If you need o want to remove a handler you can write this or similar:
    'RemoveHandler txtbox0.Click, AddressOf mytxtbox0_event_click

End Sub

Private Sub mytxtbox0_event_click()
    txtbox0.Text = "See you!"
End Sub

End Class
```

Hi, this code works in a windows forms application with a textbox added to the Form1, when you do a click in the form's textbox it changes the .text property of the textbox1. I hope you understand my code written and if any dude surges then comment. Thank you very much. And happy codding!. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class mainclass
Dim txtbox0 As TextBox = Nothing

Sub New()
    txtbox0 = New TextBox
    With txtbox0
        .Text = "Hello"
        '
        '
        '
    End With
    'When you need a handler you can write this or similar:
    AddHandler txtbox0.Click, AddressOf mytxtbox0_event_click
    'If you need o want to remove a handler you can write this or similar:
    RemoveHandler txtbox0.Click, AddressOf mytxtbox0_event_click
    '
    '
    '
End Sub

Private Sub mytxtbox0_event_click()
    txtbox0.Text = "See you!"
End Sub
```

End Class

I hope it helps to you. Enjoy coding and learn much! :)

Comment: Hello Sir! Can you help me to explain more, sorry I just start coding!

Comment: Do you know about controls and its events? If yes, the code up written shows how to reach the event created by me, which is called: mytxtbox0_event_click, when you do click in the textbox declared as: txtbox0 (This fragment of code is not totally complete to run because it needs more code lines to add the textbox to a form then you will be able to see it and do click in it). Do you want to see the complete code? :)